# provider icon beside mail

Tags: php, email, icons

I'm setting up a small tool to send mails/newsletters from out of PHP. Now I wanted to add a custom icon that shows up in every mail, but have no idea how to achive this.

There are a few companies, like Facebook and Paypal, using it already. 
The icons are at least supported on iPhones and on Sparrow for MacOSX, but possibly for many other clients...

Example screenshot from Sparrow:

[See example screenshot from Sparrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whb4z.png)

[image]

Can anybody give me a hint on how to implement something like this?

Comment: Icon has nothing to do with emails

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the RFCs for mail headers to define any icons to show. Most programs doing so will do this based on your contact list or some kind of internal association list (the case here I guess). As an alternative, the program could use services such as Gravatar, but there's really nothing you can do when composing the mails.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, there is no native solution for this. But if you only want to show up the providers-icon you can set up a table in your database with a bunch of domains and icons. Then parse the domain in the senders e-mail address and check if there is any icon in the DB.

You could also grab the favicon of the domain and show them up.

Comment: Grabbing the favicon sounds like a good idea, but this opens up holes for tracking users without them even noticing it, e.g. you use some sender address like `spam@<unique-id>.mydomain.com` and the sender would know whether the mail has been retrieved or being viewed.